# Dynamically get Swatch for a color in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

I can do this:

```
Colors.red.shade100
```

for all colors.

I need however, to be able to get different swatches, for different colors, colors that the users choose themselves. Which means that I'm unaware of those things at compile time & can't just do theircolor.swatchX.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do it dynamically, I want something that would look like this:

```
Color getSwatch(Color color, int swatch)
{return color.shade(swatch)}`
```

This obviously doesn't work since there's no "shade" function.

Comment: You like to create a colorSwatch and use like youColor.shade10, somthing like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution I'm using as there are no good APIs to get a shade from a pre-defined MaterialColor after it has been instantiated.

The idea is to create a map that holds the default value of the `MaterialColor` that you are using as the base color (you can also get this value from `Color.value` if you don't have a handle on the `MaterialColor`). The value can be referenced to retrieve its shades, which is a map of intensity (swatch) to their given value.

```
class ColorMap {
  static final Map<int, Map<int, int>> _colorToHue = {};

  static getColorToHue() {
    if (_colorToHue.isEmpty) {
      for (MaterialColor materialColor in Colors.primaries) {
        _colorToHue.putIfAbsent(materialColor.value, () => 
          { 
            50 : materialColor.shade50.value ,
            100 : materialColor.shade100.value,
            200 : materialColor.shade200.value ,
            300 : materialColor.shade300.value,
            400 : materialColor.shade400.value ,
            500 : materialColor.shade500.value,
            600 : materialColor.shade600.value ,
            700 : materialColor.shade700.value,
            800 : materialColor.shade800.value ,
            900 : materialColor.shade900.value,
          }
        );
      }
      _colorToHue.putIfAbsent(Colors.grey.value, () => 
        { 
          50 : Colors.grey.shade50.value ,
          100 : Colors.grey.shade100.value,
          200 : Colors.grey.shade200.value ,
          300 : Colors.grey.shade300.value,
          350 : Colors.grey[350]!.value,
          400 : Colors.grey.shade400.value,
          500 : Colors.grey.shade500.value,
          600 : Colors.grey.shade600.value,
          700 : Colors.grey.shade700.value,
          800 : Colors.grey.shade800.value,
          850 : Colors.grey[850]!.value,
          900 : Colors.grey.shade900.value,
        }
      );
      _colorToHue.putIfAbsent(Colors.black.value, () => 
        {
          12: Colors.black12.value,
          26: Colors.black26.value,
          38: Colors.black38.value,
          45: Colors.black45.value,
          54: Colors.black54.value,
          87: Colors.black87.value,
          100: Colors.black.value,
        }
      );
      _colorToHue.putIfAbsent(Colors.white.value, () => 
        {
          10: Colors.white10.value,
          12: Colors.white12.value,
          24: Colors.white24.value,
          30: Colors.white30.value,
          38: Colors.white38.value,
          54: Colors.white54.value,
          60: Colors.white60.value,
          70: Colors.white70.value,
          100: Colors.white.value,
        }
      );
    }
    return _colorToHue;
  }
}
```

To use it you can use a method like the following where `color` is the default color for a MaterialColor (equivalent to Colors.red, Colors.blue, etc) and `swatch` is the corresponding Material intensity (50, 300, 900, etc) defined in the map below.

```
Color getSwatch(Color color, int swatch) {
  return Color(ColorMap.getColorToHue()[color.value]![swatch]!);
}
```

A couple of things to note:

- This does not cover custom colors. To do that you will have to create your own custom swatch and add it to the map.
- The default color has to be provided. For instance, this function outputs a shade. You cannot pass in the output of this function back into the function and receive a value.
- This provides only primary colors, white, grey, and black. It does not provide accent colors. They can be added in a similar fashion by looping over `Colors.accents` and adding the appropriate intensities since they are different than primaries.
- Black and white don't have a "default" or primary value (the value returned by Colors.black or Colors.white) mapped to a shade intensity. The other colors have an intensity of `500` mapped to their primary value. Black and white are instead accessed by passing in `100` as the swatch value in the `getSwatch` function. Note that this is a custom addition in order to allow full functionality of the method.